# a more readable way to do this?

Tags: javascript

I know there is a more readable way of writing this:

```
var string = ( 
  (r.d != 0 ? r.d + (r.d == 1 ? ' day' : ' days') : '' ) +
  (r.h != 0 ? r.h + (r.h == 1 ? ' hour' : ' hours') : '' ) +
  (r.m != 0 ? r.m + (r.m == 1 ? ' minute' : ' minutes') : '' ) +
  (r.s != 0 ? r.s + (r.s == 1 ? ' second' : ' seconds') : '' ));
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to pluralize minutes and seconds when they are 1?

Comment: How about just writing day(s) or second(s)? No javascript needed :)

Comment: because if your gonna do something that uses javascript, why not do it properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something a bit more readable:

```
function singleOrPlural(val, single, plural){
  if(val == 1)
    return val + ' ' + single;
  if(val > 1)
    return val + ' ' + plural;
  return '';
}
```

Use as:

```
singleOrPlural(r.day, 'day', 'days')
```

You can even go nuts and add this to the `prototype`, and end up with `r.days.singleOrPlural('day', 'days')`, but I don't think it's needed here.

Comment: +1 because it's cleaver regarding i18n for language where plural is not word + s like German for example

Comment: nice!, please use the "triple" equivalence operator "===" in the future.

Comment: @gath - Thanks. I thought about `===`, but what would I do with `val > 1` in that case? It would create an inconsistency between `('1', 'cow', 'cows') => fail` and `('2', 'cow', 'cows') => works`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```
function pluralize(aVal, aSuffix) {
   var r = '';

   if (aVal != 0) {
      r = aVal + ' ' + aSuffix + (aVal > 1 ? 's' : '');
   }

   return r;
}

var string = pluralize(r.d, 'day') + pluralize(r.h, 'hour') + 
     pluralize(r.m, 'minute') + pluralize(r.s, 'second')
```

EDIT: renamed the function to `pluralize`

Comment: Wanted to offer the same solution. Another +1.

Comment: Here's a minified version of the function `hourify` function: `function h(v,s){return v!=0?v+' '+s+(v>1?'s':''):'';}​` (56 bytes)

Comment: The function does much more than pluralizing, it is creating the string. I like the minified version. I feel that one should be converting a string to a number and checking if its between the 0 and 60 or 0 and 24 for it to return the correct value. I am not sure if its a good idea to discuss edge cases here.

Comment: A little nitpicking @NullUserEception. As 0 is false in JavaScript you don't need to check if v != 0. A simple v?dosomething:'' is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getvalue(val, unit) 
{
        if(val>0) 
            return val + unit + (val > 1 ? 's' : '');
        else
            return '';
}

var string = gets(r.d, 'day') + gets(r.h, 'hour') + gets(r.m, 'minute') + gets(r.s, 'second');
```

Comment: This always adds `s`, and doesn't add a space between the unit and the number. Also, it is somewhat weird that it doesn't add the number to its output, you have to do it 'manually'...